# Ajax form not computing GA (_trackEvent)

Tags: javascript, ajax, analytics

I have a form at www.ritafischer.com.br/contato.html and I have tried many things but haven't been able to make GA count the event of submitting a form. So far I have the code placed at the summit button with the command =onClick.

the js handling the form is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');


    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');


        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

can anyone assist me wit this? it's driving me crazy! heheheh

Comment: What does "GA" mean? *edit* oh - "Google Analytics" ... so what part of this code you posted has anything to do with that?

Comment: Google Analytics, many people use the js to insert the google tracking code, that's why. The form is in Ajax so the user does't leave to any other page.

Comment: I understand that stuff, but I don't see anything in the code you posted that has anything to do with Google Analytics. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: this is what I have on the form code: <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contato', 'enviar',,, false]);"/>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contato', 'enviar']);

   //other code here
});
```

Comment: no, i've tried before. it's messing up the code as well. The thank you message show in a different page.

Comment: GA code shouldnt affect your Thank you message... You need to add the event.preventDefault() after the submit line if you dont want a redirect.